# Send e-mail from within the Movilizer

Tags: email, movilizer

I try to create a text item screen which can be filled out by the user. When pressing OK the entered data should be stored and - if possible - sent via e-mail (maybe as a txt-file attachment - but as e-mail text should also be suitable).

Is there a possibility open the device's e-mail browser from within the Movilizer and transfer the user input to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no out of the box way to fulfill your requirement and the workaround will not work on all platforms.

- the textItemScreens email feature does only provide the possibility to open the native browser and to pass the email address.
- webViewScreen: you can dynamically create and write a local html file and use the mailto: feature. This way you will be able to pass a subject and a body parameter, which can be filled with your data. If this is a feasible workaround depends on the used platform and the embedded browser. On Android and Windows he does not support the mailto call, but on iOS the subject and the body parameter are working. Btw, there was an attachment parameter in earlier days, but this one is no longer supported.

  http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_email_mailto.php
- and last bot not least the html5 screen. Here it should work, but I have to do some further tests.

The behavior of the Android and Desktop client has to be discussed with the developers, maybe they are able to enable this feature. I will keep you updated.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I will try the WebView workaround first. I think, this could work

Answer (score -1):

Please consider the following approach:

In case your Movelet originates from an integrated scenario, e.g. into SAP Netweaver, you could consider sending the user input to your back-end system via a reply or data container.

In the back-end system you could use all the power you have to apply formatting, mail templates, enrich or convert the content (PDF report) and then use build in functions to finally distribute the content to the recipients. Additionally the back-end could store a reference of the mail conversation, to keep track of the exchange.

In SAP ABAP there are mechanisms for that, same applies for all other sophisticated programming languages, I assume.

Hope this helps,
Tom!

Appendix:
In SAP you could evaluate class CL_BCS (Business Communication Service), but there are many more options for this.